# iOS (objective c) send post request with json to php backend

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking-3

My code in iOS:

```
NSString * some_str = @"{\"one\":\"two\",\"three\":\"four\"}";
NSData *objectData = [some_str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                       error:&error];  
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[manager POST:@"https://exmaple.com/post.php" parameters:json progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

My code in backend (PHP):

```
<?php
if(strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'POST') != 0){
    throw new Exception('Request method must be POST!');
}
$contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';
if(strcasecmp($contentType, 'application/json') != 0){
    throw new Exception('Content type must be: application/json');
}

//Receive the RAW post data.
$content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$decoded = json_decode($content, true);
echo $content;


// $responses = array();
header("Content-type: application/json, charset=utf-8");
// echo json_encode($responses);

$conn->close(); 

?>
```

If I echo $content, the response received by iOS will be some hex number. i.e. 3c21444f 43545950 (hex number for the json string start from the tail to the head connected by a "&" sign, i.e. three=four&one=two). If I echo $decoded, it returns an empty json.

And if I try to decode the json received by Post request, it failed. I believed that the received object was a possible input for json_decode function.

Should I rewrite my iOS code or PHP code or both?

Comment: you are set this line wrong: NSString * some_str = @"{\"one\":\"two",\"three\":\"four\"}";
  Reason of '\' is n't put after two please check your data.

Comment: @BhadreshKathiriya that was a typo. I will correct it. Thx.

Comment: Why do you go through NSString to construct the parameters? You do NSString => NSData => NSDictionary, and the `AFHTTPSessionManager` will do NSDictionary => NSData.

Comment: You can test your php code with postman I guess, that will narrow down the search for bug

Comment: thanks guys! I solved this problem by myself!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...may helps

Create a method and pass parameters to that method

```
+ (void)apiRequestForPOSTWithServiceName:(NSString *)serviceName andParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameter withCompletion:(void(^)(id response, BOOL isSuccess))completion
{
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BASE_URL, serviceName];
[manager POST:url parameters:parameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

    completion(responseObject,YES);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    completion(error,NO);
}];
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: could you pls tell me why?

Comment: For code reusable purpose..where ever you want just pass value to that method.

Comment: I think this is not the question was about. But thanks. I will keep that in mind.